# Function doesn't have access to variables (closures) created by other function

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, scope, closures

In my code I select some HTML inputs and add `footComparer` function as a callback.

I am trying to simplify my code a little by adding a helpers object, which will contain some helper functions.

The problem is when it hits this line:

```
 selectedSearchDropdown.style.display = '';
```

It throws a reference error:

```
selectedSearchDropdown is not defined.
```

I'm having a real trouble on grasping **why** the closures aren't working here. Isn't the `footComparer` function supposed to have access to the `selectedSearchDropdown` variable since it stays in memory as a closure?

```
const searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.searchBox__input');
searchInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', footComparer));

function footComparer(e) {
    helpers.elementSelector(e);
   selectedSearchDropdown.style.display = '';
}

let helpers = {
elementSelector: function (e) {
    let selectedSearchDropdown = e.target.parentNode.childNodes[3];
}
```

Comment: Because you very specifically declare `selectedSearchDropdown` as a variable scoped to `elementSelector: function (e)`. You probably want to `return` the value from that function?

Answer (score 1):

Check what `let` exactly is: [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

I would recommend You to read that book (it is free on github): [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures). It should help You to understand scopes, closures etc.

Basically `let` keyword creates variable inside that specific `{}`. `let` gives you the privilege to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement of expression unlike `var`, so `let` is only available inside that specific block.

`var` is rather a keyword which defines a variable globally regardless of block scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing some concepts here.

The `footComparer` function can't have access to the `selectedSearchDropdown` variable because it is defined in a different **Scope**. Some more info on scopes in javascript can be found here: [Scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)

In your particular Example, the code that would work is:

```
let helpers = {
elementSelector: function (e) {
    return e.target.parentNode.childNodes[3];
}

const searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.searchBox__input');
searchInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', footComparer));

function footComparer(e) {
   selectedSearchDropdown = helpers.elementSelector(e);
   selectedSearchDropdown.style.display = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, variables declared with `let` are only available in the scoped of the curly braces in which they have been defined.
However, you could `return` the selectedSearchDropdown.